# How up to date do bank statements need to be for a UK Visa reapplication?

Tags: visas, uk

So a month ago I applied for a UK visa, I was declined due to a simple mistake that I have now rectified around an invitation letter not specifying the dates. All my forms and supporting documents are in order however I noticed that my bank statement for my savings account is now not as recent.

When I applied last time my last transaction on said statement was October 21st, only one transaction has happened since then in the savings account however from the date of my new application (November 9th) obviously some time has passed.

The question is will the officer in charge consider the statement too old now as 19 days have passed? Will I need to travel to get another set of statements from my home branch that will provide only one very small transaction?

Comment: Was the refusal reason unconnected to your bank statements?

Comment: Yes it was due to an invitation letter not specifying the dates

Comment: AFAIK the accepted wisdom is that bank statements should be dated less than 31 days before the date of an application. The Visitor rules and guidance on required documents don’t appear to specify this, but there are references to it for other visa types eg https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/appendix-finance so it would seem a reasonable working assumption.

Comment: I know it's unlikely at this point, as the OP hasn't been online since later the same month as they posted this question, but... if you get this, please post an answer yourself letting people know what happened. It may help others.

Comment: Without seeing the actual text of the refusal letter, we are speculating that the OP's reporting is accurate and complete.